# Separate Data into Days of the week mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,

I am currently making a sales tracking report where the user pick a date range then the table should display the result.

for now I have this query that counts how many items are sold

```
select x_transaction_details.xitem, 
       SUM(x_transaction_details.qty) as totalNumberSold, 
       count(x_transaction_details.xitem) as occurence, 
       x_transaction_details.cost, 
       i_inventory.xitem, 
       x_transaction_details.date_at as transDate
from x_transaction_details
   left join i_inventory on x_transaction_details.xitem = i_inventory.xid
where (x_transaction_details.date_at BETWEEN '2015-08-13 08:34:12' AND '2015-09-14 08:34:12')
GROUP BY x_transaction_details.xitem
ORDER BY occurence DESC
```

this query displays

```
|itemName| totalNumberSold | occurence | date
|item 1  | 23 pcs          |  2        |
|item 2  | 18 pcs          |  6        |
|item 3  | 203 pcs         |  18       |
etc..
```

Now I want to know the breakdown of sales per day so I tried

```
select x_transaction_details.xitem, 
       SUM(x_transaction_details.qty) as sold, 
       count(x_transaction_details.xitem) as occurence,
       x_transaction_details.cost, 
       i_inventory.xitem, 
       x_transaction_details.date_at as transDate
       SUM(CASE WHEN date_at = DAYOFWEEK(1) THEN    
                 count(x_transaction_details.xitem) END) as Sunday
from x_transaction_details
  left join i_inventory on x_transaction_details.xitem = i_inventory.xid
where (x_transaction_details.date_at BETWEEN '2015-08-13 08:34:12' AND '2015-09-14 08:34:12')
GROUP BY x_transaction_details.xitem
ORDER BY occurence DESC
```

But its generating an error instead. I want to create a more detailed table

```
|itemName|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thur|Fri|Sat|Sun| totalNumberSold | occurence | date
|item 1  | 10|  0| 0 | 13 | 0 |0  |0  | 23 pcs          |  2        |
|item 2  | 1 |  3| 12|  0 | 16|0  |0  | 32 pcs          |  6        |
|item 3  | 0 |  6| 1 | 13 | 8 |7  |1  | 36 pcs          |  12       |
etc..
```

Thanks for the tips, I can make this table using php (hard-way) too but I guess its doable using sql query as well. Have a good day ahead.

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation, something like `SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date_at) = 1 THEN x_transaction_details.qty ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday`

Comment: yeah this is what I am trying to do in the first place but I dont know whats the format so Im getting an error.. thank you sir :)

Comment: Have a look at Gordon's answer below, it's the same syntax for all week days. You just need a separate expression with conditional aggregation for every weekday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma and nesting aggregation functions.  I think you want:

```
select i.xid, SUM(td.qty) as sold, count(td.xitem) as occurrence,
       avg(td.cost) as avg_cost, i.xitem,
       SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(td.date_at) = 1 then td.qty else 0 end) as Sunday
from i_inventory i join
     x_transaction_details td       
     on td.xitem = i.xid
where td.date_at BETWEEN '2015-08-13 08:34:12' AND '2015-09-14 08:34:12'
GROUP BY i.xid
ORDER BY occurrence DESC;
```

Notes:

- "occurrence" has two r's.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You can't nest aggregation functions.
- You shouldn't include `date_at` in the `select` list because the value is not unique for each row.
- The `left join` is either backwards (inventory should go first) or should be an `inner join`.  In a properly formed database, you should not have items in  the transaction table that are not in the inventory table (I don't think).

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir @GordonLinoff, yes there should be no items on transaction table that isnt on the inventory table, but I guess its more efficient for me to query first the transaction table since its not necessary have to go through all inventory items every time. its based on transaction date range that the user chooses..

Comment: You left cost and item as non-aggregates. I suspect that's wrong also.

Comment: hello @shawnt00 sorry I just wanted to have the 'SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(td.date_at) = 1 then td.qty else 0 end) as Sunday' code actually I didnt really cleaned my code as I posted it :)

Comment: @melvnberd . . . You should use an inner join and let MySQL do the optimization.

Comment: thanks for the tip sir @GordonLinoff I'll research on that then :) I havent used inner join since! haha

Comment: is inner join more efficient than left join sir?

Comment: @melvnberd . . . An inner join provides more possible execution paths for the optimizer to consider.  So, the optimizer can sometimes find a better execution path with an `inner join` versus an `outer join`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual code (might be helpful for anyone)

```
select x_transaction_details.xitem, count(x_transaction_details.xitem) as occurrence, i_inventory.xitem,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 1 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as Sun,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 2 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as Mom,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 3 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as tue,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 4 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as wed,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 5 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as thur,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 6 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as fri,
SUM(case when DAYOFWEEK(x_transaction_details.date_at) = 7 then x_transaction_details.qty else 0 end) as sat,
SUM(x_transaction_details.qty) as totalNumberSold
from x_transaction_details
left join i_inventory on x_transaction_details.xitem = i_inventory.xid
where (x_transaction_details.date_at BETWEEN '2015-08-13 08:34:12' AND '2015-09-14 08:34:12')
GROUP BY x_transaction_details.xitem
ORDER BY occurrence DESC
```

I did not used table aliases though :)

Comment: I think you should probably remove these columns from your output: x_transaction_details.cost, i_inventory.xitem, x_transaction_details.date_at as transDate

Comment: ohh okay @shawnt00 the 'i_inventory.xitem' though refers to the actual name of the item  and the 'x_transaction_details.xitem' refers to the item ID which is on the i_inventory table

Comment: You should get in the habit of using `min` or `max` even when all the values in the group are the same. What you're doing probably works out for the cost and name but `date_at` will not.

Comment: thank you very much for giving me some tips :) I am really not good at optimizing query yet, so its appreciated really. by the way. what does min/max do in short word? does this really help? in my case for example..

Comment: They key is to understand that `group by` has to collapse values from more than one row into a single value per group. Some systems like MySQL let you refer to a column in the way you've done but there is no way to predict which value is returned and so it's a bad practice. The minimum/maximum of values that are all the same is the value itself but the "dummy" aggregate is still necessary on systems that conform to the standard.